# selecting full row of datagridview in vb.net on form_Load

Tags: vb.net

how can i select full and first row of datagridview in vb.net on form_Load

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I´m not sure if all these lines are strictely necessary, but this should work:

```
If MyDataGridView.RowCount > 0 Then
    MyDataGridView.ClearSelection()
    MyDataGridView.CurrentCell = Me.Rows(0).Cells(0)
    MyDataGridView.Rows(0).Selected = True
End If
```

Ah, if you want to select the full row, the DataGridView Selection Mode property must be `FullRowSelect`

Answer (score 1):

```
DataGrid1.Rows(0).Selected = True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DataGridView.SelectedIndex = 0
```